# Search in HTML Table the th tag

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```

I have the following table

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>@Id</th>
        <td>Channel:0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>@Name</th>
        <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>BitCountRange</th>
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>PixelType</th>
        <td>Bgr48</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DyeName</th>
        <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>ShortName</th>
        <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>ColorMode</th>
        <td>None</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to search the th tags with the following w3 javascript tryout script:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This script is working fine if the search is based on the td tags. But I want to search the table header/columns (th).

I have tried following chances on this code:

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[0];

td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th");
```

But both is not working. I have no experience in js, and this script is for a usage in flask.

Comment: You need to add the `id` attribute to your elements if you want to use `getElementById()` to reference those elements. Like: `<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: I had forgot the input snippet. I have updated it

Comment: The table still needs the "myTable" id.

Comment: I have added it, its not working. Its working only with the td tags

Comment: I think all you needed was the `id="myTable"`. I think it is working when you use `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[0];`. But I'm not sure what you mean by "its not working".

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the table headers using getElementsByTagName and specifying th as the tag.

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>@Id</th>
            <td>Channel:0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@Name</th>
            <td>C1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>BitCountRange</th>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>PixelType</th>
            <td>Bgr48</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>DyeName</th>
            <td>C1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ShortName</th>
            <td>C1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ColorMode</th>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        //get all th's

        var ths = document.getElementsByTagName("th");

        for (let thisTh of ths) {
            console.log(thisTh);
        }
    </script>
```

Debugging this code using f12 in your browser reveals each th object and the properties available, like the text in the tag header. Simply pass in the text you are searching for to the routine above and when you find the th with the matching text.

The object thisTh will have a parentNode, as the table row, and a sibling, which is the td wiith the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `tr = table.getElementsByTagName("th");` 
with `tr = document.getElementsByTagName("th");`

I have commented out the wrong code and used the correct code in the attached snippet.

```html
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        //tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        tr = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you have more than one table in the DOM? This way you will get *all* table rows (you have there also a spelling mistake, it should be `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')` not `document.getElementsByTagName('th')`).

The original was correct in this part when it was fetching all the rows of the current table with `tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need replace `"td"` with `"th"` in the JS code the input will filter by text in the `<th>` tags.

Please review the updated code.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            // td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[0];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>@Id</th>
        <td>Channel:0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>@Name</th>
        <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>BitCountRange</th>
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>PixelType</th>
        <td>Bgr48</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DyeName</th>
        <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>ShortName</th>
        <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>ColorMode</th>
        <td>None</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```